# React.JS: Nested Filter/Map Arrays

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn React as part of a course I'm doing with Udacity. I've been battling this issue for a couple of days and can't seem to figure a way out of it.

Basically, I have an API call that returns an array of objects as a promise,  I map or filter through these (I've tried both) and need to find the elements that already exist in an array `booksOnShelves`. I do this by comparing the `.id` property of each object. Once we find a match I need to set the `.shelf` property to the same value as the one in the existing Array and if the book doesn't exist I need to set its value to `'none'`. All is good here but the problem is when I find a match the property updates the `shelf` to the correct one, but the iteration continues with the next book that obviously doesn't match and overwrites the `.shelf` value with none.

Here's the code for this particular method:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    result: []
  }

  getBooks = (query) => {
    const booksOnShelves = this.props.books;

    BooksAPI.search(query)
    .then(res => {
      if (res instanceof Array && res.length > 0) {
        res.filter( searchedBooks => {
          return booksOnShelves.filter( onShelves => {
            if ( searchedBooks.id === onShelves.id) {
              return searchedBooks.shelf = onShelves.shelf
            } else {
              return searchedBooks.shelf = 'none
            }
          })
        })
        this.setState({result: res.sort(sortBy('title'})
      } else {
        this.setState({result: []})
      }
    })
    .catch( err => { console.log('ERROR: ', err)})
  }
```

I've tried so many things but none was able to maintain the value of the shelf property.

Is there any way to stop the iteration from overwriting the matched value?

Any ideas how to achieve the intended outcome?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: btw I know I'm using filter in the code example only but I've also tried to use map to no avail.

Comment: `array.filter` is not what you want. This function will take elements out of an array when you return `false` within the function, and will keep elements in the array when you return `true`.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by your line `this.setState({result: res.sort(sortBy('title'})` since there seem to be some missing `)` characters. Do you mean for it to be `this.setState({result: res.sort(sortBy('title'))})`? (note the 2 extra `)` chars

Comment: You can use `Array.find()` which returns the first matching Object. It will stop iterating once it finds a match. Try experimenting with it where you call `.filter()` instead of filter.

Comment: Blundering Philosopher yes that is missing a couple of characters on that line, thank you, was an issue when copying the code the actual code is correct. agm1984 I will try using the filter, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem sorted with the help of all you guys I've made it work. Thanks a lot.

Just for reference here's the code that worked.

```
    BooksAPI.search( query )
  .then( res => {
    if (res instanceof Array && res.length > 0) {
        res.map( booksFromSearch => {
          booksOnShelves.find( book => {
            if( booksFromSearch.id === book.id) {
              booksFromSearch.shelf = book.shelf
              return booksFromSearch;
            } else {
              booksFromSearch.shelf = 'none'
            }
          })
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work fine in your case:

```
BooksAPI.search(query).then(res => {
if (res instanceof Array && res.length > 0) {
  booksOnShelves.forEach((book) => {
    const correspondingRes = res.find((item) => { return (item.id === book.id) });
    if (correspondingRes) {
      book.shelf = correspondingRes.shelf;
    } else {
      book.shelf = “none”;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I think in the `else` statement the OP wants `book.shelf = 'none';` right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply l1fe but I don't think this will work. `booksOnShelves` already have the `.shelf` property defined and this needs to be added to the result of the promise `res` returned by the API call. The API returns an object with no `.shelf` so we need to either return none or if the books match, they need to return the value of shelf for the corresponding book in `booksOnShelves` which is an array passed as a prop to this component. Does it make sense? I've tried to use and refactor your code but still didn't get it to work, I'll keep trying. Thanks again.